# What is the simplest way to remove multiple spaces in a string in Delphi?

Tags: string, delphi, freepascal

Let's say my string is:

```
"The   fox   jumped   over    the log."
```

It should then be turned into:

```
"The fox jumped over the log."
```

What is the simplest (1-3 lines) to achieve this, without looping and splitting the string apart?

Comment: "Without looping ..." makes this Q strange. And what does "simple" mean? How long can the lines be? Why not create a super-awesome `CollapseWhitespace` function (with loops) and then just call it every time you need it?

Comment: You ignored formatting and now (thanks to HTML features) both of your examples look the same. [Help on code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: IMHO impossible without a loop

Comment: function Magic(const _InString: string): string; begin Result := 'The fox jumped over the log.'; end; Unfortunately this is more than 3 lines when formatted properly. OK, seriously: I think you are looking for an RTL function that you can simply call. As far as I know there is no such function. https://stackoverflow.com/q/35158485/49925 is a simliar question with a few answers, but they all contain loops and are more than 3 lines.

Comment: Your requirements are so strange, that the question smells homework. Homework questions are not forbidden, but fair play requires that you inform the fact. Therefore I leave your question unanswered by me.

Comment: It is homework, as otherwise OP would have given the String's `content only` or at least `'Pascal delimiters'` instead of wrong ones. Using `goto` would avoid a (literal) loop...

Comment: There will always be looping somewhere, even when you use some replacestr, the looping is in the replacestr.  (and like Adre Ruebel shows an additional if you want to catch any length of spaces). If it is homework, and a totally open question (no hints it is somewhere in the courseware, which reduces it to "read the d*mn book"), it is flawed IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have Free Pascal in the tags, use [`DelSpace1()`](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/strutils/delspace1.html):

> *DelSpace1* returns a copy of *S* with all sequences of spaces reduced to 1 space.

The *DelSpace1* implementation is probably also more efficient than the other options presented here, but uses some FPC intrinsics for multiplatform performance(equivalent to assembler scasb/w etc)

Answer (score 2):

The Delphi RTL simply does not have any functions for collapsing consecutive spaces.  You will just have to write your own loop for this, eg:

```
// this is just an example, there are many
// different ways you can implement this
// more efficiently, ie using a TStringBuilder,
// or even modifying the String in-place...
function CollapseSpaces(const S: string): string;
var
  P: PChar;
  AddSpace: Boolean;
begin
  Result := '';
  AddSpace := False;
  P := PChar(S);
  while P^ <> #0 do
  begin
    while CharInSet(P^, [#1..' ']) do Inc(P);
    if P^ = #0 then Exit;
    if AddSpace then
      Result := Result + ' '
    else
      AddSpace := True;
    repeat
      Result := Result + P^;
      Inc(P);
    until P^ <= ' ';
  end;
end;
```

```
var S: String;
S := 'The   fox   jumped   over    the log.'
S := CollapseSpaces(S);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a one-liner...

```
  WHILE (pos('  ', s) > 0) DO s := StringReplace(s, '  ', ' ', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

...which however will become a two-liner after code formatting.
And it uses a loop which is somewhat againt the question.

Comment: This is indeed a correct approach, but it is also a *highly* inefficient approach (in terms of runtime),

Answer (score 1):

Without loops:

```
Result := StringReplace(StringReplace(S, '   ', ' ', [rfReplaceAll]), '  ', ' ', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

Explanation:

- it first replaces all occurrences of three consecutive spaces with one space
- then replaces all occurrences of two consecutive spaces with one space

Alternative (untested):

```
Result := String.Join(' ', StrUtils.SplitString(S, ' '));
```

Comment: This will fail on `'test                                                   test'`, which will give `test         test`.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I know there are limitations but it works well on the given input. The Q did not say which maximum number of blanks must be supported, so I cheated.

Comment: @mjn `StrUtils.SplitString(S, ' ')` will split on each individual space, it will not collapse consecutive spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
str := string.Join(' ','The   fox   jumped   over    the log.'.Split([' '], TStringSplitOptions.ExcludeEmpty));
```

Comment: Works in Delphi and Free Pascal, many thanks

Comment: https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/3.2.2/rtl/sysutils/tstringsplitoptions.html

Comment: This is, quote, `splitting the string apart`, which is not wanted as per question.

Comment: @KaiBurghardt `without looping and splitting the string apart` does not forbid usage of RTL methods.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to answer, I would try to be as efficient as possible and not create a "one-liner," as it likely doesn't do what you expect. I know you mention not looping, but for those who see your question and do not mind looping, I would do the following:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.RegularExpressions;

function RemoveExcessiveSpaces(const Input: string): string;
begin
  Result := TRegEx.Replace(Input, '\s+', ' ').Trim;
end;
```

A regex is looping, just not by you in your code, and without regex I would do:

```
function RemoveExcessiveSpaces(const Input: string): string;
var
  i, StartIndex, EndIndex: Integer;
  sb: TStringBuilder;
begin
  StartIndex := 1;
  EndIndex := Length(Input);

  // Find the first non-space character
  while (StartIndex <= EndIndex) and (Input[StartIndex] = ' ') do
    Inc(StartIndex);

  // Find the last non-space character
  while (EndIndex >= StartIndex) and (Input[EndIndex] = ' ') do
    Dec(EndIndex);

  // Exit if the string is empty or all spaces
  if StartIndex > EndIndex then
    Exit('');

  sb := TStringBuilder.Create(EndIndex - StartIndex + 1);
  try
    for i := StartIndex to EndIndex do
    begin
      // Append current character if it's not a space or if it's a single space between words
      if (Input[i] <> ' ') or ((i > StartIndex) and (Input[i - 1] <> ' ')) then
        sb.Append(Input[i]);
    end;

    Result := sb.ToString;
  finally
    sb.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Delphi Programming Language, you can use the `StringReplace` function from the `SysUtils` unit to replace multiple spaces with a single space. However, `StringReplace` only works on one occurrence at a time. To remove all instances of multiple spaces without looping, you can use a regular expression with the `TRegEx` class from the `System.RegularExpressions` unit.

Here's a simple way to do it in one line:

```
uses System.RegularExpressions;

// ...

ResultString := TRegEx.Replace(InputString, '\s+', ' ');
```

This line of code will replace all sequences of one or more whitespace characters (\s+) in InputString with a single space, and store the result in ResultString. Remember to add `System.RegularExpressions` to your uses clause to access the TRegEx class.

Thank you for taking the time to view my post. I appreciate your attention and assistance!